# WP Custom Post Type - Display taxonomy as CSS class

Tags: arrays, wordpress, taxonomy

I have set up a custom post type in wordpress called "Portfolio". The custom post type then has two taxonomy's set up. They are named 'portfolio_categories' and 'portfolio_sector'.

Currently i am using the following code to gather all my 'portfolio_categories' and store them so they can then be outputted as CSS class to be used for filtering.

```
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
 $termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "portfolio_categories" );  //Get the terms for this particular item
 $termsString = ""; //initialize the string that will contain the terms
 foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) { // for each term 
 $termsString .= $term->slug.' '; //create a string that has all the slugs 
}
?>
```

Then the code to output the terms as classes is as follows:

```
<div class="<?php echo $termsString; ?>">
Content goes here
</div>
```

How would i need to edit my code in order to store the taxonomy 'portfolio_sector' and output them as classes also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also get your others terms data, in your context

```
<?php
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
  $the_query->the_post(); 
  $termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "portfolio_categories" );  //Get the terms for this particular item#
  $termsSectors = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "portfolio_sector" );
  $termsString = ""; //initialize the string that will contain the terms

  foreach ( $termsSectors as $term ) { // for each term 
    $termsSector .= $term->slug.' '; //create a string that has all the slugs 
  }

  foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) { // for each term 
    $termsString .= $term->slug.' '; //create a string that has all the slugs 
  }
}
```

Now you can echo this via the var `$termsSector`.

However, as a hint you can also work with [`get_the_term_list()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list) to get a list include HTML. Maybe this is easier for you and it is not necessary to loop about the array of the terms.

Comment: thanks for your answer! It worked! It is now posting both the categorie and sector as a class. However it starts to post the sector class more than once after the first item. Can you see what i mean from this screenshot? https://ibb.co/k5sMU7

Comment: Yes, you doing the term loop (foreach) inside the WordPress loop (while) and this have the result, that you echo the class for each post.

Comment: Okay, i am trying to understand. Why does the same not happen to 'portfolio_categories' as the class service-one is only posted once for each.

Comment: maybe categories don't have so much terms? It is not easy to help you without all of your code in this template.